# MySQL WHERE...IN query

Tags: php, mysql

In the below code, the 4th line is creating an error "AND 'user' IN(SELECT 'user_s' FROM 'sex' WHERE sex='$iaminterestedin')".  Basically I am trying to only include users from the user_s column of the gender table for who the sex column = $iaminterestedin.  Yet this is producing an error.  The WHERE... NOT IN query works fine but is there such a thing as WHERE ...IN query?

```
$result = queryMysql("SELECT `user` FROM `members`
                WHERE `user` NOT IN(SELECT `ilike` FROM `likeprofile` WHERE user_l='$user')
                AND `user` NOT IN(SELECT `dislike` FROM `dislikeprofile` WHERE user_d='$user')
                AND 'user' IN(SELECT 'user_s' FROM 'gender' WHERE sex='$iaminterestedin')   
                AND `user` <> '$user'");
```

Comment: Switch the single quotes to backquotes.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: Or don't quote them at all. `user` is not a reserrved word.

Answer (score 0):

Table name should be surrounded with backticks and not quotes

```
AND `user` IN(SELECT `user_s`
    ^----^           ^------^ use backticks ` instead of quotes '
```

Comment: Also in the sub-SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $result = queryMysql("SELECT `user` FROM `members`
            WHERE `user` NOT IN(SELECT `ilike` FROM `likeprofile` WHERE user_l='" . $user . "')
            AND `user` NOT IN(SELECT `dislike` FROM `dislikeprofile` WHERE user_d='" . $user . "')
            AND `user` IN(SELECT `user_s` FROM `gender` WHERE sex='" . $iaminterestedin . "')   
            AND `user` <> '" . $user . "'");
```

You should use backticks, not qoutes. Also you need to end the string to input the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
            AND 'user' IN(SELECT 'user_s' FROM 'gender' WHERE sex='$iaminterestedin')   
                ^----^--- wrong quotes. Use ` instead
```

Comment: Also in the sub-SELECT.